# How to loop through SQLite rows?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I would like to design login and registration forms with SQLite DB. I made registration table with three fields and login form with two fields.

```
Registration form:
User Name:
Password:
RetypePassword:

Login form:
User Name:
Password:
```

If any user try to login for the first time we should provide a message to register.i.e, we need to iterate through registration table and check whether login fields are already present or not.

So here I'm missing the logic (loop) to iterate through all the records of registration table.

```c
- (void) loginBtn:(id)sender
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_registerDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM registertable;"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_registerDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *regUserName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                NSString *regPassword = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",regUserName,regPassword];

                [arr addObject:str];                

                //************************LOOP ?????????????

                for(int i=o;i<arr.count;i++){

                    if([loginUserTxtFld.text isEqualToString:??????] && [loginPasswordTxtFld isEqualToString:??????])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"login successful");
                    }

                    else{
                        NSLog(@"You have not yet registered");

                    }                            
                }

                _statusLabel.text = @"Match found";
            } else {
                _status.text = @"Match not found";
                _regUserNameTxtFld.text = @"";
                _regPwdTxtFld.text = @"";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(_registerDB);
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to have this loop through the selected rows?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate through the loop ? just SELECT * FROM registertable WHERE User Name = %@"   Also define your userName field as an index

Comment: @RyanHeitner Correct, use `WHERE` clause to do the work for you. But never use `stringWithFormat` to build SQL with `%@` printf-style formatters. Use `?` placeholders and bind values with `sqlite3_bind_text`. Or use something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) that takes care of this hassle for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop, replace

```
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // this only retrieves one row
}
```

with

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // this will be performed for each row
}
```

But, even better, why don't you have SQLite do this work for you?

```
// NB: Do not use `stringWithFormat` to build this SQL, but rather use `?`
//     placeholders and then call `sqlite3_bind_text`

const char *query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM registertable WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_registerDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_registerDB));
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [loginUserTxtFld.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"bind userid failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_registerDB));
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [loginPasswordTxtFld.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"bind password failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_registerDB));
}

int rc = sqlite3_step(statement);
if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // userid/password found
} else if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
    // userid/password not found, but no error
} else {
    NSLog(@"step failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_registerDB));
}

// continue with finalize, close, or whatever else
```

Clearly, I don't know the names of your userid and password fields, so alter this SQL accordingly, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.